# Azure Active Directory Open Id connect for the id_token it returns an expiration time of -1

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I had implemented Azure Active Directory open id connect. It was working well for 2 months. The HTTP `expires` header is not returning `-1`.

Did something change with Azure Active Directory?

EDIT:
Here is what the token contains:
[image]

[image]

On the second screen shot we can see that the expiring time is -1. Is that relevant?

Comment: Could you show the id token contents? Obviously remove your personal info from there.

Comment: @juunas I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

That header is not relevant. It is used to tell browser not to cache the response. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires

In the token you can see it is valid from Thursday, January 18, 2018 6:12:09 PM UTC (the `nbf` claim) to Thursday, January 18, 2018 7:17:09 PM UTC (the `exp` claim). So one hour.

Comment: I found what was the problem. Since Azure AD does not support CORS. I had previously added the signinkeys in my setup file. I believe the signinkeys change? Now I added all three signinkeys. Seems to be working. But I think I will change to B2C soon. Regardless, your help was appreciated it opened my mind to dig deeper for other issues. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah the token endpoint does not support CORS since you are not supposed to call it from JavaScript. Kind of preventing you from shooting your own foot. And usually signing keys are acquired by the app on startup from the well known URL. You should not typically hard-code them, though they do not change often.

Comment: yeah but to get the signinkeys, cors is also an issue so it is again blocked. Therefore I had to hard-code them. :(

Comment: That's true.. That actually raises the question: Does ADAL.JS check the id token signature? In a sense, fabricating an id token for JS would only net you access to front end stuff, and APIs would not accept a fake access token anyway.

Comment: yeah, I actually had a lot of trouble setting openid connect in my backend, because for some reason the backend was always storing it in cookies. I did not know how to retrieve the id_token or the acccess_token. So I went with this library in react to do it in the front end. But as you can see I had a lot of problem :(. Now that I know more about how it works, I might be able to set up a backend for the login that will return the access_token and id_token to the frontend. But regardless I should've set up B2C in the first place.